# Opal file called from client via getsctipt (or xhr'ed and evaled) can't be evaled and used

Tags: opalrb

I want to xhr some opal script, and use ruby code defined there. I tried to get it with $.getScript. But no success for me.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'assets/foo.js.rb',
  success: function(data){
    #{ClassInFooJs.new}
  },
  dataType: "script"
});
```

Moreover the script is evaled (in strange manner), I mean I can call Opal.modules["file_i_required"] from console, and it will return basically the compiled code.

BUT inside of it nothing is evaled, (no console.logs, `window["foos"] = #{something}`), and I can't reference anything from that file.

Any help?

Comment: Uhm, solved it, either `Opal.modules["foo"](Opal)` from native should be called, or `require "foo"` from opal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use either `require "foo"` from Opal or `Opal.require("foo")` from JavaScript. If the `load "foo"` behavior is required should be noted that `Opal.load("foo")` is also present.

The alternative is to compile files on the server with the `:requirable` flag set to `false` but that's kinda difficult unless you compile manually. See the [API docs](https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/e6f327e5793306a7add19e8714cf5bd51dca4a7e/lib/opal/compiler.rb#L65-L105) for more info.

Calling directly `Opal.modules["foo"](Opal)` should be avoided as it doesn't properly update `$LOADED_FEATURES` and in general can change in the future.

Comment: Thank you Elia, both for the answer and for your priceless contributions to Opal.